# Windows 10 wireless issue: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

On a brand new Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming I'm facing issues when connecting to home wireless: the connection to internet sometimes fails (for browser, steam and other applications) but I can correctly connect to the router config page. Other devices connected to the same wireless are working fine and if I connect to the network using a cable the issue disappears.
It seems to be related to upload traffic, but I could be wrong on this point.
I've tried quite all the solutions found (reset winsocks and others) but nothing worked. All the drivers are up to date.
Any help would be really appreciated!

EDIT: I'll clarify my question to avoid being too broad.
The problem is: the new laptop is having problems accessing internet, only in wireless. Other devices on the same wireless are accessing internet without problems and the same laptop is working fine when connected with the cable.
How can I investigate the issue deeper?
I don't think is a connection issue, because when I get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on internet sites, I can access the router configuration page without problems. It's not a browser issue, because also Steam and other applications (dropbox for example) are encountering problems. Perhaps some kind of wireless card configuration issue?

EDIT 2: Adding additional details as requested in comments:

1. The router is a TP-Link TD-W8970
2. The other devices (iPad, smartphones) are working without issues when the laptop is experiencing internet connectivity problems
3. My wireless interface is a Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265, as said before the laptop is a brand new Dell Inspiron 15 7000 Gaming
4. I have tried to investigate the issue trough the router management page, but I found no clues. I've now tried to add a reservation for my wireless card MAC address, I'll see if this can change something.

**I finally understood that the problem is probably related to an upload issue**: if I do a speedtest on internet (for example on speedtest.net) the upload bandwith is stick at 0.0 and the test is stopped complaining for a socket problem. After this test, the browsers show the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error and dropbox/steam stop working.
Another laptop in the same time completed correctly the same test and the upload speed is 0.81 Mbps.

Comment: Compare your IP/Subnet/Default gateway/DNS to the other devices.

Comment: Already done, configuration is the same and it's provided by the DHCP

Comment: Reboot you router that provide Wi-Fi and try connecting again and seeing it that resolves it. Also, disable and then re-enable the WLAN NIC and check afterwards. Before you start chasing ghosts though, consider doing a simple Wi-Fi router reboot just in case as I have seen this be needed before when too many DHCP addresses are given out before leases expire and even when the router assigns a valid IP, etc. In one case it seemed to affect DNS where public IP worked but just not DNS from what I vaguely recall and simple rebooting the ISP Wi-Fi AT&T router resolved in that one case—simple to try!

Comment: This sounds like a weird problem, and I don’t know what to do about it. But one of the real reasons why people close questions as “Too broad” is that they believe that you haven’t provided enough information. For example, what brand/model router do you have? Can you tell what kind of wireless card the PC has? It might not really be important, but you should probably mention *in the question* that you use DHCP.  Have you checked whether you’re getting a new DHCP lease right around the time you're having a problem? Can you do any troubleshooting from the router home page?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Do other devices on your network function correctly *at the exact same time* that the PC is failing?  Etc.     Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Thanks Scott for your hints, I updated the question. I know this is quite a weird issue, but I'm getting mad with it so I finally decided to post my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I finally found the solution! (Hurra!)

It was a problem related to upload and Windows 10 updates, that were installed when I first switched on my new laptop. Disabling the virtual network adapter in the devices manager solved the issue, as showed in [this link](https://pureinfotech.com/fix-wifi-disconnecting-problem-windows-10-fall-creators-update/).
I'll look which feature I lost disabling this adapter, but at the moment this workaround seems to work.